# Solidity compile Error: Expected primary expression help

Tags: solidity

**Compile Error**

I cannot understand why this happens.I copied and pasted this code from `https://zoom-blc.com/how-to-create-first-dapp`

Error message is as follows:

```
truffle(develop)> compile
Error parsing /Users/akitasatoshi/pet-shop-tutorial/contracts/Adoption.sol: ParsedContract.sol:10:3: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
  　 return petId;
  ^
```

The code is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Adoption {

  address[16] public adopters;

  function adopt(uint petId) returns(uint) { 
    require(petId >= 0 && petId =< 15);
    adopters [pedId] = msg.sender;
    return petId;
  }

  function getAdopters(uint) public returns (address[16]) {
    return adopters;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- There's no closing brace on your `contract`.
- There's a space in the line `adopters [pedId]`.
- There's a typo in the same line. `pedId` -> `petId`.

The actual issue you've reported is due to `=<`, which should be `<=`.

---

**Edit:**

> I copied and pasted this code from...

Okay, I tried copy+pasting from that site, and Remix didn't like it. There seem to be some special characters at the beginning of each line that are causing problems, specifically `U+3000`, which is the "[Ideographic Space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3000)" character. Might be related to it being a Japanese site? Don't know.

Removing any whitespace from the beginning of each line, then re-indenting using a "normal" space/tab gets things working.

Comment: Firstly, sorry for lots of typos..  Thank you! I could compile them. I did not notice the "Ideographic Space", so wondered error which indicating blank.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar error when defining an `event`. The problem was that I was defining it inside of a function, when it should have been at the contract level.